# What might have gone wrong if I'm receiving the following error message?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transfer

I've been trying to transfer monero but it keeps getting stuck on pending, 0/10 confirmations.

I'm certain I have the address correct, I reinstalled my wallet, I updated it, I re-synchronized, I don't think my antivirus is getting in the way. I don't know what else to try and was thinking people here would probably know?

I'm getting this error message: 'Couldn't generate a proof because of the following reason:
daemon returned wrong response for gettransactions, wrong txs count = 0, expected 1'

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you using a local or remote node?